# Ruby unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

I get the following error from my code.

> ruby -w search.rub search.rub:19: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'case' at 12 search.rub:62: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

I have a feeling that it has something to do with all the ends.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

num_line = 0
NumDiccionario = 1

def checkPassword (pass)
  print pass, "\t"
  system("bitcoind", "walletpassphrase", pass, "20")
  case $?.exitstatus
  when 0
    puts "You found it!#{pass}"
    File.open('password.txt', 'w') do |file|
      file.puts phrase + "\n"
    end
  exit 0
end

str_num_line = "0"

File.open('lastLine.txt', 'r') do |file2|
  str_num_line = file2.gets
end 

if (str_num_line.to_i > 0 )
  print "Last searching stopped at line " + str_num_line + "\n"
  STDOUT.flush
  print "Continue from here? y/n:" 
  resp = gets.chomp
  if (resp == "y")
    num_line =str_num_line.to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: I really appreciate any help, lost a password to a very important file of mine, this ruby script appears to be just what i need.

Comment: should be the entire script, when i remove the very last 'end' i get search.rub:61: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Comment: You are missing the `end` keyword for your case statement.

Comment: Wow thank you guys so much! I really appreciate it, all is good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def checkPassword (pass)
  print pass, "\t"
  system("bitcoind", "walletpassphrase", pass, "20")
  case $?.exitstatus
  when 0
    puts "You found it!#{pass}"
    File.open('password.txt', 'w') do |file|
      file.puts phrase + "\n"
    end
  end
  exit 0
end
```

Comment: You should point out in this code where the missing 'end' has been inserted.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, getting closer, says search2.rub:32: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end